# How to run a package within the Anaconda environment?

Tags: python, anaconda

I am a beginner, and trying to run a package, Trimmomatic, that is located within the Anaconda environment. I have tried to extensively google how to actually run a program within the environment and I cannot find anything. I usually code in bash so this is all new to me. Any help would be fantastic! 
I am able to load the environment:

```
module load anaconda/2-4.2.0_cent
source activate base
```

But I have no idea how to get the package to run. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do mean by run the package? You mean use it by importing them?

Comment: There is a program named Trimmomatic that I utilize in my metagenomic pipeline, which i run remotely on a super computer from my command line. It used to be loaded just onto the super computer, but recently has been moved to be included within the anaconda environment. I am able to get into the anaconda environment but I cannot figure out how to get the program to run. Again, I code in bash and have no idea how to use python, nor am I very proficient in coding. I apologize if i used the wrong terminology previously.

Answer (score 2):

When you install anaconda you're given the option to add it to your `$PATH`, and the default option is no.

Putting the anaconda directory in your path is a necessary first step, as this allows you to use the `conda` command which gets used a bunch.

I'm going to assume you installed anaconda to `/home/me/anaconda3/`. If you installed Anaconda2, change `anaconda3/` to `anaconda2/`.

First off, do the following:

```
~$ [export] PATH="/home/me/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
~$ conda --version
conda <X.Y.Z>
```

After you've confirmed `conda` is in your path, you'll already have access to the `base` env, but you can double-check with:

```
~$ conda env list
# conda environments:
#
base                  *  /home/me/anaconda3
~$ which python
/home/me/anaconda3/bin/python
```

If you want to create a new `venv`, conda makes that extremely easy:

```
conda create python=2.7 -n py27env
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: /home/me/anaconda3/envs/py27env

added / updated specs:
  - python=2.7


The following packages will be downloaded:

package                    |            build
---------------------------|-----------------
wheel-0.31.1               |           py27_0          62 KB
python-2.7.15              |       h1571d57_0        12.1 MB
certifi-2018.8.13          |           py27_0         139 KB
pip-10.0.1                 |           py27_0         1.7 MB
setuptools-40.0.0          |           py27_0         583 KB
------------------------------------------------------------
                                       Total:        14.6 MB

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

ca-certificates: 2018.03.07-0
certifi:         2018.8.13-py27_0
ncurses:         6.1-hfffgggg474d3e_0
openssl:         1.0.2p-h14c325_0
pip:             10.0.1-py27_0
python:          2.7.15-h1571e57_0
readline:        7.0-ha6073c88_4
setuptools:      40.0.0-py27_0
wheel:           0.31.1-py27_0
zlib:            1.2.11-ha838bed_2
...

Proceed ([y]/n)?
```

Now just press yes, conda will do it's thing, and you'll get a little prompt about how to use `source activate`, and you're good to go!

For completeness, here's a couple more lines of bash to double-check:

```
~$ source activate py27env
(py27env) ~$ which python
/home/me/anaconda3/envs/py27env/bin/python
(py27env) ~$ conda env list
~$ conda env list
# conda environments:
#
base                     /home/me/anaconda3
py27env               *  /home/me/anaconda3/envs/py27env
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: see the thing is, i did not install anaconda. Anaconda is installed on a remote server/supercomputer that I log into via the command line. I have permissions to use anaconda but cannot install anything. I'm able to load up the anaconda environment, all I'm trying to do is run a program that is within the anaconda environment.

Comment: What happens when you type `which conda`?

Answer (score 0):

Type `conda list` to verify that the package you want to run is installed in the current environment. If you are not in the correct environment, type `conda activate env_name` (where `env_name` is the name of the environment you want to activate).

If the package you want to run is listed when you type `conda list`, then you can run it directly. Try by just typing the package name. If not, try `python -m package_name`.